# Change from fmt.Printf to exec.Command

Tags: go

How can I change the code instead of showing it (fmt.Printf) to execute a command (exec.Command)

Now I have this:

> // Print keys
>   fmt.Printf("%x %34s %34s\n", padded, uaddr.EncodeAddress(), caddr.EncodeAddress())

How to give a variable value to 'g' and 'h':

```
    v := "cmd"
    n := "/C"
    a := "testcmd"
    b := "-connect=127.0.0.1"
    c := "-port=3333"
    d := "-user=username"
    e := "-password=password"
    f := "importaddress"
    g := "AddressHere"
    h := "MoreInfo"

    z := exec.Command(v, n, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

    if err := z.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
```

I need to give this variable valie:

```
h := fmt.Printf("%x\n", padded)
g := fmt.Printf("%34s\n", uaddr.EncodeAddress())
g := fmt.Printf("%34s\n", caddr.EncodeAddress())
```

execute the command twice with different variables

Comment: Use fmt.Sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmt.Sprintf()`

Example:

```
g := fmt.Sprintf("%s", uaddr.EncodeAddress())
```

Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string. You can then use this same value for your variables.